# Print first matching line

Tags: bash, sed

Using `sed`, I would like to print the first matching line of a file. I would like only the matching line itself, no other lines. This is a similar command that will print the last matching line

```sh
$ sed '/while/h; $!d; g' foo.sh
while read video
```

Inspired by [aragaer’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15451819), this seems to do it

```
$ sed '/while/q;d' foo.sh
  while sleep 1
```

Comment: Why not simply use grep and head?

Comment: `grep -m1 while foo.sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/while/!d;q' file
```

Answer (score 6):

```sh
sed -n '/LINE TO MATCH/{p;q}'
```

- -n means "don't print anything unless said to"
- p - print
- q - stop and exit

Both p and q will fire on matching line.